# How to access a python argparse argument with a dot in the name

Tags: python, argparse

Python's argparse lets me define argument names containing a dot in the name. But how can I access these ?

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inputfile.txt")
parser.add_argument("outputfile.txt")

args = parser.parse_args(['hello', 'world'])

# now args is:
# Namespace(inputfile.txt='hello', outputfile.txt='world')


# and this does not work
print(args.inputfile.txt)
>>> AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'inputfile'
```

Obviously attribute names can be created with a dot in their name but how can these be accessed ?

Edit:
My goal was to let argparse display the inputfile.txt name (e.g. with --help) but call the attribute "inputfile".

After trying some of the suggestions the easiest way to accomplish this is using the metavar option:

```
parser.add_argument("inputfile", metavar="inputfile.txt")
```

Comment: Yes, a clean `dest` and a `metavar` for the help is the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, `argparse` will add all attributes to the `Namespace()` instance with [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr). Accordingly, you can access the values with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(args, 'inputfile.txt')
```

However, this is not as intuitive and in general attribute names with dots in them should be avoided.  It is recommended to use the [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) option of [`argparse.add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) to define your own variable in which to store the value for that argument, as hd1 suggests in their answer.

Comment: Nice. getattr works. However using the dest option as suggested results in ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument

Comment: Doh, yeah consulting the `argparse` source it looks like for positional arguments (e.g. args not starting with '-') `dest` is not supported.  So I would either make the arg optional, rename it, or else you can just get by on `getattr`

Comment: Thanks. I've added my original goal (to see "inputfile.txt" using --help but name the attribute inputfile) which can be accomplished using metavar

Answer (score 4):

Rename the argument to `inputfile` and use `metavar` to set the display value for the user.

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inputfile", metavar = "inputfile.txt")
parser.add_argument("outputfile", metavar = "outputfile.txt")

args = parser.parse_args(['hello', 'world'])

# now args is:
# Namespace(inputfile='hello', outputfile='world')

print(args.inputfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the dest option, you can assign it to anything:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inputfile.txt", dest='infile')
parser.add_argument("outputfile.txt", dest='out')

args = parser.parse_args(['hello', 'world'])
# now args is:
# Namespace(infile='hello', out='world')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you mean the [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) option.  Also, small typo on first `metavar`

Comment: nice catch, @lemonhead!

Comment: This results in ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [FileType](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) objects instead?

```
>>> import argparse
>>>
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--infile', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--infile'], dest='infile', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=FileType('r'), choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('--outfile', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--outfile'], dest='outfile', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=FileType('w'), choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--infile', 'input.txt', '--outfile', 'output.txt'])
Namespace(infile=<open file 'input.txt', mode 'r' at 0x100f99e40>, outfile=<open file 'output.txt', mode 'w' at 0x100f99ed0>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to refactor your code to change the argument name.
But, if you won't or can't, this will do the job:

```
args.__dict__['inputfile.txt']
```